# Web Service conflict among cxf2.2.4 Spring2.5.6 and jboss 7?

Tags: spring, jboss7.x

How do I want to set up web service on Spring 2.5.6 cxf2.2.4 and jboss7?

I know jboss 7 has web service package natively. My codes already heavily rely on apache cxf2.2.4 framework, I just don't want to change a lot due to tight deadline. I put this under webapp/META-INFO/ to exclude embeded cxf2.4 in jboss7, what else should I do?

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
       <module name="org.apache.cxf"/>
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Something really blocking me is when I want to use current cxf2.2.4, it seems that jboss7 requires me to add MappedName attribute to @Resource in it. I downloaded cxf2.2.4 from SVN and tried to change the source code, but I failed to make a new jar because lack of some dependencies(they may be too old to get).

Or I need to upgrade to cxf 2.4.1 natively on jboss7, which may take quite a long time.

ERROR MESSAGE I got with cxf2.2.4:

> ```
> 03:04:51,418 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version
> ```
>
> 1.0.1.GA
>       03:04:52,219 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.0.GA
>       03:04:52,303 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBoss AS 7.0.0.Final "Lightning"
>   starting
>       03:04:54,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as] creating http management service
>   using network interface (management) port (9990) securePort (-1)
>       03:04:54,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] Removing bootstrap log
>   handlers
>       03:04:54,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class
>   org.h2.Driver (version 1.2)
>       03:04:54,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
>       03:04:54,282 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) Activating Infinispan subsystem.
>       03:04:54,472 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   Activating Naming Subsystem
>       03:04:54,490 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4)
>   Starting Naming Service 
>       03:04:54,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   Activating OSGi Subsystem
>       03:04:54,522 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) Activating Security Subsystem
>       03:04:54,529 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4)
>   JBoss Remoting version 3.2.0.Beta2
>       03:04:54,561 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO
>   Version 3.0.0.Beta3
>       03:04:54,588 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO
>   NIO Implementation Version 3.0.0.Beta3
>       03:04:55,006 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ee] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   Activating EE subsystem
>       03:04:55,141 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener]
>   (MSC service thread 1-7) The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows
>   optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin;.;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows7Master;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Thunder Network\KanKan\Codecs;C:\Program
>   Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\mysql\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\maven303\;D:\maven303\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\IDM Computer
>   Solutions\UltraEdit\;D:\FuhuAppStore\software\eclipse-jee-indigo-win32\eclipse;
>       03:04:55,178 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread
>   1-7) Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
>       03:04:55,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jmx.JMXConnectorService] (MSC
>   service thread 1-2) Starting remote JMX connector
>       03:04:55,251 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC
>   service thread 1-3) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
>       03:04:55,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread
>   1-1) Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.0.CR2)
>       03:04:55,524 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]
>   (MSC service thread 1-1) Bound data source
>   [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
>       03:04:55,524 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Bound data source
>   [java:jboss/datasources/musicstore]
>       03:04:55,525 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]
>   (MSC service thread 1-6) Bound data source [java:jdbc/mysql/appstore]
>       03:04:55,525 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Bound data source
>   [java:jdbc/mysql/appsubmission]
>       03:04:55,912 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment] (MSC service thread
>   1-6) Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory
>   D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
>       03:04:55,948 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBoss
>   AS 7.0.0.Final "Lightning" started in 5221ms - Started 105 of 160
>   services (55 services are passive or on-demand)
>       03:04:55,959 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-5) Starting deployment of "asweb.war"
>       03:05:08,589 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-2) Class Path entry xbean.jar in
>   "/D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/asweb.war/WEB-INF/lib/js.jar" 
>   does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
>       03:05:08,590 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-2) Class Path entry jaxp-api.jar in
>   "/D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/asweb.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api-1.3.jar"
>   does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
>       03:05:08,590 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-2) Class Path entry jax-qname.jar in
>   "/D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/asweb.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api-1.3.jar"
>   does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
>       03:05:08,590 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-2) Class Path entry activation.jar in
>   "/D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/asweb.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api-1.3.jar"
>   does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
>       03:05:08,591 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-2) Class Path entry servlet.jar in
>   "/D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/asweb.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api-1.3.jar"
>   does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
>       03:05:08,591 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-2) Class Path entry saaj-api.jar in
>   "/D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/asweb.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar"
>   does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
>       03:05:08,591 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-2) Class Path entry activation.jar in
>   "/D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/asweb.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar"
>   does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
>       03:05:08,592 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-2) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in
>   "/D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/asweb.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.jar"
>   does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
>       03:05:08,592 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-2) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in
>   "/D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/asweb.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.jar"
>   does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
>       03:05:09,035 INFO  [org.jboss.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) read
>   persistence.xml for asjpa
>       03:05:09,473 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.headers.HeaderManagerImpl/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.headers.HeaderManagerImpl since it's missing a "lookup"
>   (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,473 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.bus.resource.ResourceManagerImpl/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.bus.resource.ResourceManagerImpl since it's missing a
>   "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,473 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl since it's missing a "lookup"
>   (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,474 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.buslifecycle.CXFBusLifeCycleManager/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.buslifecycle.CXFBusLifeCycleManager since it's missing
>   a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,475 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextResourceResolver/bus on
>   class org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextResourceResolver
>   since it's missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any
>   known type
>       03:05:09,475 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.catalog.OASISCatalogManager/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.catalog.OASISCatalogManager since it's missing a
>   "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,475 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.RMManager/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.RMManager since it's missing a "lookup" (or
>   "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,476 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.WSSecurityPolicyLoader since
>   it's missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known
>   type
>       03:05:09,476 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerRegistryImpl/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerRegistryImpl since it's missing a
>   "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,477 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImpl/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImpl since it's missing a
>   "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,478 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.workqueue.WorkQueueManager on class
>   org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl since it's missing a
>   "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,478 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.AttachmentInputInterceptor/supportedTypes
>   on class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.AttachmentInputInterceptor
>   since it's missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any
>   known type
>       03:05:09,479 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManagerImpl/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManagerImpl since it's missing a
>   "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,479 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.wsdl.WSDLExtensionRegister/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.wsdl.WSDLExtensionRegister since it's
>   missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,479 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   transportIds on class org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaBindingFactory
>   since it's missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any
>   known type
>       03:05:09,480 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory since it's
>   missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,480 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory since it's missing a
>   "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,480 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   activationNamespaces on class
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory since it's missing a
>   "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,481 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl since
>   it's missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known
>   type
>       03:05:09,481 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.management.counters.CounterRepository since it's
>   missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,481 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractDataBinding since it's
>   missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,481 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSTransportFactory since it's
>   missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,482 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.DestinationFactoryManagerImpl/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.DestinationFactoryManagerImpl since it's
>   missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,482 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPTransportFactory
>   since it's missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any
>   known type
>       03:05:09,482 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine since
>   it's missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known
>   type
>       03:05:09,483 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory
>   since it's missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any
>   known type
>       03:05:09,483 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiatorManagerImpl/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiatorManagerImpl since it's
>   missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,483 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory since
>   it's missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known
>   type
>       03:05:09,484 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name:
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.QueryHandlerRegistryImpl/bus on class
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.QueryHandlerRegistryImpl since it's
>   missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:09,484 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPTransportFactory since
>   it's missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known
>   type
>       03:05:09,484 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.ee.component.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't handle @Resource for ENC name: cxf on
>   class org.apache.cxf.transport.local.LocalTransportFactory since it's
>   missing a "lookup" (or "mappedName") value and isn't of any known type
>       03:05:11,089 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC
>   service thread 1-2) Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
>       03:05:11,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployment of "asweb.war" was rolled
>   back with failure message {"Services with missing/unavailable
>   dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"asweb.war#asjpa\" missing [
>   jboss.data-source.java:/ ]"]}
>       03:05:11,384 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Service status report
>          New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>             service jboss.data-source.java:/ (missing)
>
> ```
> 03:05:11,386 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment]
> ```
>
> (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"Composite operation failed and was
>   rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Services
>   with missing/unavailable dependencies" =>
>   ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"asweb.war#asjpa\" missing [
>   jboss.data-source.java:/ ]"]}}}
>       03:05:20,618 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-6) Stopped deployment asweb.war in 9226ms
>       03:05:20,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (MSC service thread
>   1-8) Service status report
>          Newly corrected services:
>             service jboss.data-source.java:/ (no longer required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue as I was deploying a standalone WAR in Tomcat but was moving to Jboss7AS.  After all the sesarching and even Jboss employee support telling me "don't use CXF in your WAR use the Jboss Jax-WS" I got it working.  In my /WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml I chose to exclude all EE packages and this made my WAR work just find that was deploying in Tomcat deploy on Jboss7 AS.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <!-- For JBoss7AS and WS-Security/CXF to play nice must exclude the EEjars -->
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```