# mapped-name is required for org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBaseBindingFactory/bus of deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jboss, cxf

I am using JBoss AS 5.1 with Java 1.6.0_22 and get the following error when I try to deploy my dynamic web project through Eclipse. I am using Apache CXF v2.7.18 and have auto generated .java files through "Generate Java Bean Skeleton" from a wsdl file. What does `mapped-name is required for org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBaseBindingFactory/bus of deployment` mean? I looked on various websites but came to no solution.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: mapped-name is required for org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ConduitInitiatorManagerImpl/bus of deployment MySimulator.war
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXmlResourceEnvRefs(WebResourceHandler.java:287)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXml(WebResourceHandler.java:325)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processMetadata(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:550)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.WebCtxLoader.start(WebCtxLoader.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4272)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.AbstractDeployHandler.start(AbstractDeployHandler.java:263)
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.AbstractDeployHandler.invoke(AbstractDeployHandler.java:177)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.local.LocalClientInvoker.invoke(LocalClientInvoker.java:106)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1724)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:629)
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.StreamingDeploymentTarget.invoke(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:305)
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.StreamingDeploymentTarget.start(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:190)
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.start(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:231)
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.run(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:88)
    at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.run(DeploymentUtils.java:120)
    at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.deployArchive(DeploymentUtils.java:103)
    at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.ApplicationServerComponent.createContentBasedResource(ApplicationServerComponent.java:400)
    at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.ApplicationServerComponent.createResource(ApplicationServerComponent.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.ResourceContainer$ComponentInvocationThread.call(ResourceContainer.java:482)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any help would be appreciated as I can't make any sense of it.

**Additional Info** (Auto generated by Eclipse):

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
          version="2.5">
    <display-name>Myproject</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

cxf-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="theSchema.xsd" id="myserviceport"
        implementor="myservice.MyservicePortImpl"
        wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/myservice.wsdl" endpointName="tns:myservicePort"
        serviceName="tns:myservice" address="/myservicePort">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jboss comes prepackaged with cxf libraries. So, you will not need the apache cxf dependency at runtime and should be excluded from the deployment assembly if you go with Jboss CXF integration. You may have to tweak the jboss deployment descriptor to make it all work.

So one way or the other you'll have to decide which one you want to use and change accordingly.

Hopefully all the class loading issues will resolve themselves once you have right set up in place.

**Update**

After spending some more time,  I realized it's safe to use the jboss cxf integration for web services.

The problem you're running into is jboss trying to inject resources before cxf libraries have a chance.

In your case as you're using jboss 5 version which doesn't come with cxf libraries. So easy way to solve your problem will be to install cxf module in jboss server and then you can exclude the apache cxf binaries from your application deployment.

I gave it quick test locally and it worked fine.

Let me know if you're still looking for solution, I can add more steps on installing cxf module in jboss server.

Comment: Is the web.xml the deployment descriptor or jboss-web.xml? If the latter, I don't have that file. I guess I'll have to make one. Can you give me a guide of some sort on how I should make and tweak it? I'm new to all this so it would help me out tremendously as I do not know what to search for. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Can you add web.xml and other cxf configuration files to the post ? Are you using spring ?

Comment: Please use these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370879/jboss-start-exception-due-to-apache-cxf and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888102/web-service-conflict-among-cxf2-2-4-spring2-5-6-and-jboss-7. These links will help you exclude the jax ws module from jboss so you can use your application cxf libraries.

Comment: I added `web.xml` and `cxf-beans.xml` which were auto generated by Eclipse to the OP. I'll check out those links as well. Thank you!

Comment: I tried many different exclusions and each one just changes the "is required for ..." part. Always a different class saying "mapped-name is required". I'm not sure how to proceed.